# With Ubuntu 14.04 host with kernel 3.13.0-151 all my kvm virtual machines crash on boot

Tags: 14.04, kernel, kvm-virtualization

My kvm virtual machines are Ubuntus and Windows 10. All went well as far my host uUunbtu 14.04 updated its kernel to 3.13.0-151. After that both Ubuntu and Windows 10 virtual machines crash on boot. If I boot host with previous kernel 3.13.0-149, virtual machines work OK as they have used to do for years.

Host uses amd 64 bit processor.

Now there is available kernel version 3.13.0-153. Does it correct kvm problem or must I wait this problem to be solved?

Comment: I tried kernel version 3.13.0-157-generic which is current last Ubuntu kernel version available, but no, problem still continues as it started with kernel version 3.13.0-151. Kernel version 3.13.0-149 is the last that can run kvm Windows and Linux guests.

Comment: I don't know reason of the problem but there may be some change in kernel dependencies in version, because when I was running kernel 3.13.0-149 and avoided updating kernel with update manager, running apt-get reported that kernel was kept back and this means often dependency problem between current and new version of package.

Anyway, problem is serious.

Comment: What I see from the ubuntu guest boot log is "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill Init!"

Answer (score 0):

This problem  was not newer solved. But time has handled it. Ubuntu 14.04 is not supported any more and it seems, that with Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS same virtual servers with KVM/qemu virtualisation that worked with 3.13.0-149 but not newer kernels, work fine with Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS newest kernels.